# Rule for manipulate an expression

Tags: rule

like as my precedent post
I have this Expression:

```
 (5 Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[e, 6])/(
 5 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 2] + 
  89 Subscript[e, 14] Subscript[e, 5] + 
  7 Subscript[e, 92] Subscript[e, 56] Subscript[e, 6]) + 6/(
 8 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 6] + 
  89 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 9] Subscript[e, 5] + 2) + (
 89 Subscript[e, 3] Subscript[e, 4])/(
 8 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 8] + 
  89 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 9] Subscript[e, 5] + 
  7 Subscript[e, 6] Subscript[e, 92] Subscript[e, 56]) + ... + Other simils terms
```

through a rule I want obtain :

```
((5 Subscript[e, 26])/(
 5 Subscript[e, 12] + 89 Subscript[e, 145] + 
  7 Subscript[e, 92566])) + (6/(
 8 Subscript[e, 16] + 89 Subscript[e, 195] + 2)) + ((
 89 Subscript[e, 34])/(
 8 Subscript[e, 18] + 89 Subscript[e, 195] + 7 Subscript[e, 69256])) + ..+
```

Like a my precedent post i tried :

```
expr /. HoldPattern[Times[s : Repeated[Subscript[e, _]]]] :> Subscript[e, StringJoin @@ ToString /@ Last /@ {s}];
```

but not work :(

Any idea?

I apologize if the question is not clear.

Comment: @Dr. belisarius I'm sorry, what do you mean ?

Comment: @Dr. belisarius nothing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the `FullForm` of an example expression, (`expr`):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`FullForm` of this expression is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Observe that it has many sub-expressions with either three or two multiplications of a subscripted `e`:

```
Times[integer_Integer, Subscript[e, a_], Subscript[e, b_],Subscript[e, c_]]
Times[integer_Integer, Subscript[e, a_], Subscript[e, b_], mult___]
```

`mult` can be a `Power` term or not present, either is OK.

The strategy is to do replace the subscripted terms with a single subscript with the integers concatenated.

For example in the two subscript case we form `ab` by converting `a` and `b` to strings, joining them and then converting back to an integer.

All we need do is use `ReplaceRepeated` rather than `ReplaceAll` which will repeatedly apply the rule until there is no further change.

```
expr //. {
  Times[integer_Integer, Subscript[e, a_], Subscript[e, b_], 
    Subscript[e, c_]] :> 
   Times[integer, 
    Subscript[e, ToExpression[ToString[a] <> ToString[b] <> ToString[c]]]],

  Times[integer_Integer, Subscript[e, a_], Subscript[e, b_], mult___] :> 
   Times[integer, 
    Subscript[e, ToExpression[ToString[a] <> ToString[b]]], mult]
  }
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Jack LaVigne you have been very clear , thanks ! :D